# Including Nuget Package details with TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

Today I had some issues with my Nuget packages and had to update all of them.

Now I had a lot of unknown files coming up in my commit log. I added them and pushed as you can see:

[image: Show Log]

Was that the right thing to do? Do we include Nuget package data files in source control ? Please let me know if you need for information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should exclude packages folder via `.gitignore` file

```
# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
packages/
```

and exclude them to reduce repository size and get them [via automatic package restore during build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#enabling-and-disabling-package-restore).

[image]